# UWP Property Set is called multiple times when RaisePropertyChanged is called

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP application with MvvmLight. On the creation page I open a content dialog to select a category and send it via the MvvmLight messenger to the main ViewModel.

Subscribtion to the message is done here:

```
    public void Subscribe()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Register<CategorySelectedMessage>(this, async message => await ReceiveMessageAsync(message));
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Unregister<CategorySelectedMessage>(this, async message => await ReceiveMessageAsync(message));
    }

    private async Task ReceiveMessageAsync(CategorySelectedMessage message)
    {
        if(SelectedPayment == null || message == null)
            return;
        SelectedPayment.Category = mapper.Map<CategoryViewModel>(await mediator.Send(new GetCategoryByIdQuery(message.CategoryId)));
    }
```

The category property is:

```
private CategoryViewModel? categoryViewModel;
public CategoryViewModel? Category
{
    get => categoryViewModel;
    set
    {
        if(categoryViewModel == value)
            return;
        categoryViewModel = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The message is sent here:

```
MessengerInstance.Send(new CategorySelectedMessage(category.Id));
```

and this is the message:

```
public class CategorySelectedMessage
{
    public CategorySelectedMessage(int categoryId)
    {
        CategoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

As soon as RaisePropertyChanged is called the set is called again twice but with null. The "ReceiveMessageAsync" Method is only called once so I'm kinda confused where those additional calls are coming. If I comment out RaisePropertyChanged there are no more duplicated calls, but obviously the UI doesn't get updated. I also checked the callstack and can't see duplicated calls.

In case it helps the whole project is on Github under: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/tree/fix-crashes

The process is when adding a payment and select a category.

Answer (score 0):

Okay stupid me didn't remove the combobox I was replacing. That one had a two way binding on it which caused this.